# jQuery ajax method does not work in Internet Explorer

Tags: jquery, ajax, internet-explorer, utf-8, cjk

I have the following piece of jQuery code working in every browser (Firefox, Chrome, Opera) but is not working in Internet Explorer. It's a div with a shopping cart and is showing the products in Chinese. But when it comes to Internet Explorer it shows squares instead of the Chinese characters (horror story).

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong or how to fix it?

```
function geturl(addr,mydata) {  
    var r = $.ajax({  
    type: 'GET',  
    url: addr, 
    data: mydata, 
    contentType: "text/html; charset=UTF-8",
    scriptCharset: "utf-8" ,
    async: false  
    }).responseText;  
return r;  
 }
```

It even works in Firefox, Chrome and Opera without the lines:

```
    contentType: "text/html; charset=UTF-8",
    scriptCharset: "utf-8" ,
```

I've just added those 2 lines to see if that was the problem in IE.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do the headers of your page and response to the AJAX request look like? What do the meta tags of your page look like? I would try to ensure all specified encodings are the same (although it should not matter if the encoding of the page and AJAX response differ).

Comment: <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />

Answer (score 0):

IE always have a problem that doesn't have another browser. Try with this [link](http://www.jp41.com/internet-explorer/chinese/) (only for client).

Now, for your ajax request, I don't know if [htmlentities.js](http://phpjs.org/functions/htmlentities:425) can be applicable for chinese charset. Might be better that before sending the result of the ajax request transform the info into html entities (in php you can use [htmlentities()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php) )

Comment: I suppose the link you wrote http://www.jp41.com/internet-explorer/chinese/ is to show Chinese in Internet Explorer. That's is working ok in the whole page but it's not working in the div with ajax. Htmlentities.js does not work either. Thanks anyway.